# JTextField and JButton login page

Tags: java, swing

```
ublic class TheMedicalResourceManagementSystem 
{
    JFrame jf;
    JPanel jp;
    JButton b;
    JTextField t;
    JTextField t2;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TheMedicalResourceManagementSystem cc = new TheMedicalResourceManagementSystem();

       // SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GUI("The Medical Resource Management System").setVisible(true));   
    }

    public TheMedicalResourceManagementSystem()
    {



        jf = new JFrame("Frame");
        jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jf.add(jp);
        t = new JTextField(15);
        jp.add(t);
           t2 = new JTextField(15);
        jp.add(t);
        jp.add(t2);

b= new JButton("Login");
jp.add(b);

        jf.setSize(200,200);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        String username = t.getText();
        String password = t2.getText();

         b.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
             if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("password"))
             {
                 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GUI("Medical Remote Management System").setVisible(true));
             }

             else
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Incorrect username or password , Please try again");
             }});

}


}
```

within my program i am looking to enter a username and password and when it is entered and correct it should run everything. I cant get it to run as when i enter admin and password it keeps telling me the user or password is wrong even though it is not?

Answer (score 1):

Like most GUI frameworks, Swing is event driven.  This means that information is relative to the time it is collected.

In your example above, you are getting the `username` and `password` even before the UI is fully realised (presented to the user), so it will only return the initial values of the text fields (which are probably blank)

Instead, you need to get the `username` and `password` at the time of the `ActionEvent`, as that's when it's most relevant to the code, for example...

```
b.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    String username = t.getText();
    String password = t2.getText();
    if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("password")) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GUI("Medical Remote Management System").setVisible(true));
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Incorrect username or password , Please try again");
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked ! how would you go about hiding this form ? would it involve using dispose within the if?

Comment: Well, in your case, I'd do some research into using "modal dialogs", it will solve other issues you're about to encounter, but yes, `dispose` would be the most common way to dispose of window you no longer needed